# How to provide credentials for global init.gradle pluginManagement for Gradle 5.6.2+?

Tags: gradle, nexus

After the recent security fixes in Gradle 5.6.2+, we're unable to use global plugin management in init.gradle script.

The section, which is described in the [Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugin_management) does not provide any help about using Nexus server requiring authentication.

The workaround I've found is following: I had to manually hardcode credentials inside of the script even though the nexusUsername and nexusPassword is already defined in gradle.properties.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url "https://nexus-repo-requiring-auth/"
            credentials {
                username nexusUsername
                password nexusPassword
            }
        }    
}

settingsEvaluated { settings ->
    settings.pluginManagement.repositories {
        //This is a workaround, because the global properties are not available here
        def localNexusUsername = "nexusUser1"
        def localNexusPassword = "nexusPass1"
        maven {
            url "https://nexus-repo-requiring-auth/"
            credentials {
                username localNexusUsername
                password localNexusPassword
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way, how to read global variables inside of the settingsEvaluated block? Or any other way to define the plugin repository?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a solution, but a different work-around. I found that if I defined my plugin repositories in the `settings.gradle` file it was able to read the variables:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        maven {
            authentication {
                basic(BasicAuthentication)
            }
            url "https://artifactory.redacted.com/gradle-plugins-mirror/"
            credentials {
                username "$artifactory_user"
                password "$artifactory_password"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This worked better for me as we add the `~/.gradle/init.gradle` file for each user, so everyone uses the same internal mirors.